# Como ordenar uma lista pelo options select vuejs

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Boa noite, ja fiz essa pergunta, mas vou tentar melhora-la, estou desenvolvendo em laravel vue e preciso apenas jogar a função de ordenar para o option dentro do select, é algo simples, mas que eu não estou encontrando o problema, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço muito

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou chamando o método da função dentro do th  com v-on:click
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

só que eu quero altera-la para o usuário setar pelo option no select, assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código do mesmo se encontra assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e a lógica se encontra assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se deseja melhorar a pergunta, basta editar a pergunta original (em vez de duplicá-la). Além disso, se quer melhorar, coloque o código como texto e não como imagens (leia o [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052) para entender melhor)

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte maneita
 <select v-model="ordemAuxCol" class="form-control mx-sm-3">
          <option
            v-on:click="ordenaColuna(index)"
            v-for="(titulo,index) in titulos"
            :value="index"
          >{{titulo}}</option>
        </select>

Answer (score -1):

O v-for tem que estar dentro de uma tag option e esta tem que está dentro de um select. E o select tem que ser colocado dentro da tag th para que você consiga concretizar um formato de seleção de opção para ordenação da coluna.

E o v-on:click tem que fazer referência a cada option desencadeando uma ação a cada click em cada option.

Pelo menos, foi isso que entendi do seu código.

Até mais e bom trabalho colega.